# How can I convert this code LINQ to SQL in C # LINQ to SQL in Vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq-to-sql

How can I convert this code LINQ to SQL in C # LINQ to SQL in Vb.net

```
    public IQueryable<Maestro_Clientes> GetMaestro_Clientes()
    {
        var q = from co in this.Context.Cli_Consumos
            group co by new
            {
                Servicio = co.Servicio,
                Cliente = co.Cli_Servicio.Cli_Cliente.Nombre ,
                Tarifa = co.Cli_Servicio.Cli_Tarifa.Descripcion ,
                Sector = co.Cli_Servicio.Sector,
                Sector_Nombre = co.Cli_Servicio.Cli_Sector.Descripcion 
            }

            into grp
                select new Maestro_Clientes
                {
                    Servicio = grp.Key.Servicio,
                    Nombre = grp.Key.Cliente,
                    Tarifa = grp.Key.Tarifa,
                    Sector = grp.Key.Sector,
                    Sector_Nombre = grp.Key.Sector_Nombre,
                    Consumo_Energia = grp.Sum(co => co.Consumo_Energia)
                };

        return q;
    }
```

Telerik and Developer Fusion not convert well

Comment: converting with Developer Fusion or Telerik is lost or field list

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried any of the online converters? i.e. [Developer Fusion](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) or [Telerik](http://converter.telerik.com/)

Comment: I tried both of them, and they both seem to fail when it comes to converting the anonymous type constructs.

Answer (score 0):

Try [SharpDevelop's CodeConverter](http://codeconverter.sharpdevelop.net/SnippetConverter.aspx).  It works best if you give it a whole function or class.